# Receive the "Login failed for user 'sa' " when trying to connect Servoy 8 to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, sql-server-2014

I am trying to connect a SQL Server 2014 database into Servoy 8 but I am receiving the following error:

[image: Error image]

The password for the user 'sa' is correct such as the links. I searched everywhere but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: The password is correct and you sure like you've tried it in SSMS (today) and it was successful?

Comment: Use profiler to see what password is being used when the login fails.

Comment: @TabAllemanProfiler will never show you a login's password by design. Most you can do is audit a Login activity.

Comment: Does the password contain characters such as a semi-colon (;) or single quote (') ? If so there are many apps that'll fall over with those passwords.

Answer (score 0):

You should check SQL Server error log for this error. There will be two rows, one containing 18456 error with the *state* and the second decoding what the state means. It can be not only a bad password, the login can be disabled or the server can be configured to use windows authentication only